# Vue3 composition API - accessing child ref

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am trying to access a ref in a child component using the Vue3 composition API, but i am unsure of how to do so. I would like to add a scroll event to the `mainContentRef` so i can do a fetch request to grab more data within the parent component but i can't seem to access the ref in the parent component to add the event listener to it

This is my code (some parts removed due to being unnecessary for this example):

```
<!-- MAIN COMPONENT -->
<template>
    <PageWrap>
        <template v-slot:content>
            <MainContent>
                <template v-slot:content />
            </MainContent>
        </template>
    </PageWrap>
</template>

<script setup>

//access mainContentRef here because this is where the fetch request will be

</script>


<!-- MAIN CONTENT COMPONENT -->
<template>
    <div id="main-content" ref='mainContentRef'>
        <slot name='content'></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>

    import { defineProps, ref } from 'vue';

    const mainContentRef = ref(0);

</script>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could utilize vue's [`defineExpose`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose) method and then add a `ref` for your `MainContent` component and access it through that.

```
<!-- MAIN COMPONENT -->
<template>
    <PageWrap>
        <template v-slot:content>
            <MainContent ref="mainContentComponent">
                <template v-slot:content />
            </MainContent>
        </template>
    </PageWrap>
</template>

<script setup>
    const mainContentComponent = ref()
    
    // Now you can do:
    mainContentComponent.value.mainContentRef.value
</script>


<!-- MAIN CONTENT COMPONENT -->
<template>
    <div id="main-content" ref="mainContentRef">
        <slot name='content'></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    
    const mainContentRef = ref(0)
    
    defineExpose({
        mainContentRef
    })
</script>
```

See Also: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#ref-on-component

Let me know if you have any questions or it doesn't work, happy to help!

Comment: Oh wow, i didn't know you could do that! I'll try the `defineExpose` method as i've not come across this! I'll try and implement it and see how it goes! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Using define exposed within the main content component and using a ref on the child component worked wonders! I have successfully logged out the div which will (hopefully) now allow me to attach my event listener onto it! Thank you!

Comment: you're using `defineExpose` but importing `defineProps`, is it intentional or mistake?

Comment: `mainContentComponent.value.mainContentRef.value` ... this is not cool.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```js
<!-- MAIN CONTENT COMPONENT -->
<template>
    <div id="main-content" ref='mainContentRef'>
        <slot name='content'></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>

    import { defineProps, ref } from 'vue';

    const mainContentRef = ref(null);

     // Now you can do:
     mainContentRef.value.children[0]

</script>
```

Comment: How is this any better then the accepted answer that actually using a child component.

Comment: @Whitespacecode it took me time to read and understand the difference after I saw your comment. and now I just realized that it's a cool trick.